# How to create a Timer in C of fixed Duration

Tags: c++, c

How to create a timer of 200µs in C/C++?

Just perform some task in that time and then timer reset and after every 200µs keeps performing the same task?

Comment: C or C++? Those are different languages with different time facilities.

Comment: Not only are C and C++ different languages, there are also operating system facilities or framework code for this too that would differ.

Answer (score 1):

C++ has [std::chrono::high_resolution_clock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock) which **may** have nanoseconds precision.

> ...represents the clock with the smallest tick period provided by the
>   implementation.

Standard time functions in C aren't very precise. ~15ms error you can expect.

**For waiting:** Unix implementations provide [usleep](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep) and [nanosleep](http://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep). On Windows you can use [CreateWaitableTimer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682492%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([example](https://gist.github.com/Youka/4153f12cf2e17a77314c)).

**For current time:** Unix provides [clock_gettime](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/clock_gettime.html), Windows [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/dn553408%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Implementing a timer class which uses these time functions shouldn't be much work but if you use a good framework probably a high resolution timer is already available.

Answer (score 0):

Example windows code for a thread. Note that cpu usage will be 100% for the core running this thread.

```
/* code for a thread to run at fixed frequency */
typedef unsigned long long UI64;        /* unsigned 64 bit int */
#define FREQ   5000                     /* frequency */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfFreq;               /* 64 bit frequency */
LARGE_INTEGER liPerfTemp;               /* used for query */
UI64 uFreq = FREQ;                      /* process frequency */
UI64 uOrig;                             /* original tick */
UI64 uWait;                             /* tick rate / freq */
UI64 uRem = 0;                          /* tick rate % freq */
UI64 uPrev;                             /* previous tick based on original tick */
UI64 uDelta;                            /* current tick - previous */

    /* ... */ /* wait for some event to start thread */
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&liPerfFreq);

    QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
    uOrig = uPrev = liPerfTemp.QuadPart;

    while(1){
        /* update uWait and uRem based on uRem */
        uWait = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) / uFreq;
        uRem  = ((UI64)(liPerfFreq.QuadPart) + uRem) % uFreq;
        /* wait for uWait ticks */
        while(1){
            QueryPerformanceCounter((PLARGE_INTEGER)&liPerfTemp);
            uDelta = (UI64)(liPerfTemp.QuadPart - uPrev);
            if(uDelta >= uWait)
                break;
        }
        uPrev += uWait;
        /* fixed frequency code goes here */
        /*  along with some type of break when done */
    }
```